# Jquery Animate to work on input submit button?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I have a href button on which has a piece of javascript animation which makes a basket jump up and down on hover. However, I need to change the href link to an input submit button and I cannot seem to get the animation to work properly with the input button.

This is the javascript I am using for the animation

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".button").hover(function(){
            $(":not(:animated)", this)
                // first jump  
                .animate({top:"-=6px"}, 200).animate({top:"+=6px"}, 200)
                // second jump
                .animate({top:"-=3px"}, 100).animate({top:"+=3px"}, 100)
                // the last jump
                .animate({top:"-=2px"}, 100).animate({top:"+=2px"}, 100);
        });
    })
</script>
```

and this is the HTML

```
<div class="addbasketbut"> 
<a class="button" href="#">
    <img src="template_images/basketbutton.png" alt="" />Add to Basket
</a>
</div>
```

Here is a working Jsfiddle of the orignal button http://jsfiddle.net/tcherokee/wkfrG/

I'm not too experienced with Jquery, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One potential approach:

for the input button, you can use a background image in CSS to cover the SUBMIT button (I think this is possibly the only way to do it)

in order to animate the image, you could use `$('.button').animate({"backgroundPosition": POSITION})` on hover, where you would change the background image position of the SUBMIT button

Comment: Hello IanO, Thanks for the suggestion, but it won't work. The reason is that the button makes use of two images. One background image to style the button itself (which does not animate) and another image which gets animated. I have already styled the input button with the first background image, but I cannot seem to get the second image to animate. I tried enclosing the input button in a div and add the image to the div, but that just animates both the image and input button.

Comment: At the moment I can get both images to animate as can be seen in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tcherokee/KYsCj/5/. but I just want the basket image to animate instead of the entire button.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Figured it out.

I updated the jquery code to this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(".addbasketbut").hover(function () {
    $(".image:not(:animated)", this)
    // first jump  
    .animate({
        top: "-=6px"
    }, 200).animate({
        top: "+=6px"
    }, 200)
    // second jump
    .animate({
        top: "-=3px"
    }, 100).animate({
        top: "+=3px"
    }, 100)
    // the last jump
    .animate({
        top: "-=2px"
    }, 100).animate({
        top: "+=2px"
    }, 100);
});
})
```

and the html to this

```
<div class="addbasketbut">
<img src="template_images/basketbutton.png" class="image" alt=""/>
<input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit">
</div>
```

That seems to work. I am not sure if it is the most elegant solution... but it works so :).